# Firebase functions in same project but multiple apps

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

In same Firebase project I have a node app with several functions and another app with only scheduled functions (because for some reason, I encountered side effects if deployed together in same app).

Each time I deploy the app with only scheduled functions, it tells me that other functions are not present in the source code (obviously) and asks me if I want to delete them.

Is there a way to tag functions as permanent and avoid each time to have to chose to not delete them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy Cloud Functions through the Firebase CLI, it expects that you pass it a `index.js`/`index.ts` that contains all the functions for that entire project.

There is no way to tag certain Cloud Functions as permanent. I usually explicitly tell Cloud Functions what functions I'm deploying in situations such as yours, with `firebase deploy --only functions:function1,function2`.

For more on this option, see the reference documentation on [deploying specific functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#deploy_specific_functions). The option to group the functions sounds especially useful for your scenario, as you could group them by app.

Comment: Grouping suggestion is good enough for my use case, thank you.